# Why body background-image more then body size?

Tags: html, css

When I set background-image for `<body>`, the background image is larger then the body and the html size. Why is that?

```
html {
    height: 0;
}

body {
    height: 0;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832__340.jpg);
}
```

But the image occupies the entire area viewport. I don't want fix it. I want to know why background-image for body has this behavior

Comment: Please update your questions to provide a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Because you probably assigned a large image to the background. If you want the image to fit, use the property `background-size: contain`

Comment: @Ibu It seems to be the answer. Why don't you post it?

Comment: Because it is an assumption, and the OP hasn't provided enough details to answer for sure.

Comment: I have to say that this question is a common one, and not worthy of the down-votes it has received. The question is clear, and the behaviour is reproducible from the code supplied. For the answer though, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

```
html {
    height: 0px;
}

body {
    height: 0px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832__340.jpg);
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

Is this what you want?

---

**OLD**

Can u try maybe to add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

or

```
background-size:100%
```

or

```
background-size: contain
```

or

```
background-size: cover
```

or maybe anything about. Please showcase part of code that peoples here can help you

Comment: If the height is `0` then the image will never be displayed.

Comment: True, I just give him what he want. He can control height of the background image with height of html and body tag